# getting Application crash when retrieving values from one activity to another

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps

i am creating one activity   for Map and other one is for plugin i want lats and long from plugin to add marker position  on map but its getting crash.

Here is Plugin Activity

```
 this.callbackContext = callbackContext;
    context=this;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this.cordova.getActivity(),MapsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("lat", "23.074");
    intent.putExtra("lon", "47.230");

    this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);

    if (this.cordova != null) {
        this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this, intent,101);
        return true;
    }
     return false;
```

and here is maps activity

```
  //drawing marker
    double pointOneLat = Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getExtras().getString("lat"));
    double pointOneLang = Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getExtras().getString("lon"));


    pointOne = new LatLng(pointOneLat, pointOneLang);

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pointOne).title("Point 1"));
```

//

thanks....

Comment: Why you calling both startActivity and startActivityForResult in same function, call startActivity in else part of if cordova is null

Comment: May be you are trying to call direct map Activity and lat and lon  are not getting in your activity so that its null and your activity  crash.First call Plugin and pass that parameter to activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are trying to call direct map Activity and lat and lon are not getting in your activity so that its null and your activity crash.First call Plugin and pass that parameter to activity